# Finding an object with autoit

Tags: google-chrome, autoit

Using auto-it I need a to find the most recently opened tab in Google chrome and close it, I have absolutely no idea how to approach this, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: A Finding objects command would be amazing, as this would allow me to make more complex scripts.